# How to get the values from an object path

Tags: java, grails

I have a class and its controller.In the controller i am defining as below:

```
//controller 
def empData = new Employee(name:'test',joinDate:'03-Jan-2010',qualifications:['Developer','Tester'])
println("emp Info:"+empData);
```

//class

```
import groovy.transform.ToString
@ToString
class Employee{
public String name
public Date joinDate
public Map<String,String[]> qualifications
}
```

[image]

In the `println` i see the path of the object like `com.Employee@515` How to 
get all the details of the `empData` object instead of path?

Comment: In the groovy way it would be: `println empData.properties` . Check out: http://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#properties

Comment: @Michal_Szulc Hi i tried your way and in the output i see the value as below:                                                                                               parameter values are:[class:class java.util.ArrayList, empty:false]

Comment: Are you working on a persisted instance of Employee? If not, use `empData.save()` in advance

Comment: @Michal_Szulc - I dont want to save those values in the database.

Comment: oh, so why even bother about creating Employee object? `println params` or ensure that Employee is not a domain class.

Comment: @Michal_Szulc - i modified my question to give more details about my problem.

Comment: `println object.properties` is working fine, even for not persisted objects: https://majkesz.pl/images/tmp/groovy_properties.png

Comment: @Michal_Szulc  - i added the image for the same code.

Comment: Oh, is it so hard to spot the difference? Just remove access modifier `public` and it's working fine.

Comment: @Michal_Szulc - i want it to be public.

Answer (score 0):

I couple of different things you can do:

Like the comment said you can define you own toString() method in the Domain object and do what you want like this for example:

```
String toString() {
    String name = ""
    if (lastName) name = name+lastName
    if (firstName) name = name+", "+firstName
    if (middleName) name = name+" "+middleName
    name = name+" - "+position
    name = name+" - "+city
    return name
}
```

Also you could just print the fields from your object:

`println("emp first name Info:"+empData.first_name);`